# python 3 basic string syntax error

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu

I sincerely apologize as this question has been asked repeatedly and i understand that the answer is that in python 3 that the print has been made a function and that the string has to be encapsulated within parentheses. However, in IDLE, there is only 1 line of code and i have tried this one line with both single and double quotations and achieved the same "syntax error" Any help would be greatly appreciated.
If i run the same code in the shell, i have no issues!

[image: python 3 basic syntax error]

Even if i use the basic help() command i get a "syntax error"

[image: help syntax error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a python file you don't need any of the things that are printed when the shell starts up.  Your problem isn't with the `print` or the `help`, it's with the format of the file.  Take out everything before the `help()` and that should fix your problem.